# Undefined index error on key that has been declared

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am building a leaderboard (scorebored) for a poker tournament. My aim is to echo data to a table to display scores for the season and scores all time. I want the table to run in order with the highest season points at the top.
I am getting an error message that reads:

`Notice: Undefined index: season in C:\wamp\www\UPT Site\leaders.php on line 11`

When I `print_r` an array from the `$allplayers` array, it shows that all the players arrays are going in correctly, including the `[season]` key and value declared on line 6 in the bit below...

Can anyone please tell me how to fix my code? (note, the real code doesn't have line numbers in it, I just added them here to make discussion easier).

```
1  foreach($allplayers as $player){
2  $i = $player[1];

3  if (${"seasonplayerid" . $i}){

4  $sum = array_sum(${"seasonplayerid" . $i});}
5  //$sum = points this season.

6  ${"playerid" . $i}['season'] = $sum;
7  }

8  function val_sort($array,$key) {      
9  //Loop through and get the values of our specified key 
10 foreach($array as $k=>$v) { 
11 $b[] = strtolower($v[$key]); 
12 } 
13 asort($b); 
14 /*   foreach($b as $k=>$v) { 
15      $c[] = $array[$k]; 
16  }return $c; 
17 */  
18 }
19 $sorted = val_sort($allplayers, '[season]'); 


20 foreach($allplayers as $player){
21    $i = $player[1];
22    echo ("<tr><td>" . $player[0] . $t . ${"playerid" . $i}[3] . $t . ${"playerid" . $i}[4] . $t. ${"playerid" . $i}['season'] . $t. count(${"seasonplayerid" . $i}). "</td><tr>");

23 }
```

Here is the `print_r` output for array `$playerid1`:

Array ( [0] => Jonathan Thompson [1] => 1 [2] => 2015-S 3 [3] => 944 [4] => 7 [season] => 470 )

Here is a key of the information in the array:

```
/* 
$allplayers is a multidimentional array, containing many arrays of players called $playerid1, $playerid2, $playerid3 etc
        playerid1[0] = Player name
        playerid1[1] = Player ID
        playerid1[2] = Current season 
        playerid1[3] = total points earned
        playerid1[4] = total games played games
        playerid1[season] = points earned in current season
 */
```

Comment: Include the array you are using and the line numbers are not necessary; most people here can count :)

Comment: post data in $allplayers

Comment: @Tunna182 There no key like `season` in the `$allplayers` array

Comment: @sandeepsure oops, thanks for the tip. I wrote that comment before naming the key. The `print_r` output does pickup the key name as `[season]`. Thanks for letting me know. I'll fix that now.

Comment: @Tunna182 You are welcome :) , You can upvote the comment and mark the answer as updated. So, it build confidence to other for adapt.

Comment: @sandeepsure I've upvoted the comment, but I still have an unsorted array ($allplayers) and still have the `Undefined index: season` error, so I've not marked the question as "Answered" just yet.

Comment: @Tunna182 can you provide me your expected output in `$sorted` array when i pass `$allplayers` in `val_sort()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like at line 19 you are trying to pass key in second parameter but defined it incorrectly.So, to call `function val_sort($array,$key)` you have to do something like that.

```
Therefore at line 19 change 

$sorted = val_sort($allplayers, '[season]');
```

to

```
  $sorted = val_sort($allplayers, 'season');
```

Also i suggest you to use [data table](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) it is good and fast

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and mine?

Comment: @sandeepsure you are missing the explanation

Comment: It is already understood by the code when there is a small difference.

Comment: it is a good practice to give explanation i think you should understand

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but it is still giving me the error message.
If it helps I have added the result of `print_r` to better illustrate the array `$playerid1` to the question

Comment: @Tunna182  There no key like 'season' in the `$allplayers` array which you pass in `val_sort()` function.

Comment: @sandeepsure , Please see reply in thread above :) Thanks for the tip

Comment: @rocky please see my comments in the last answer. Thanks for your help with the data table tip and link :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of below line

```
 $sorted = val_sort($allplayers, '[season]');
```

you should  pass the key as below

```
$sorted = val_sort($allplayers, 'season');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did a dodgy quick fix in this instance.
I wrote a loop to array_pop each array inside the main array, and created a new variable for each piece of data as the `array_pop` loop was going.
I also `array_push`ed the data I wanted to sort by and an ID number to a new array.
I used rsort to sort the new array, then looped through it using the ID number to reconstruct a 3rd array in the order I wanted to output data.
Next time I will take the advice of @rocky and do a data table. I may even go back to redo this page as a data table. To be honest, I'd never heard of a data table before yesterday. Once I've given this project over to the boss I'll be investing my time in learning about data tables and AJAX.
Thank you all for your tips, but the quick fix will have to do this time as I am time poor (This site needs to be live tomorrow morning).